# is it possible to repair an erased bios?

Tags: bios

I am using a Jetway motherboard for 14 years. A few months ago the battery of the computer was exhausted. So my computer was working without a battery.

Last week in an attempt to update my bios, I ended up with an erased bios. Now my computer is not booting at all.  Is there any way to repair the problem?

Comment: You'll have to flash the bios. See if your computer manufacturer provides the BIOS file and then follow the instructions for your computer make and model at bios-mods.com .

Comment: Are you actually talking about an ERASED bios or just the settings got erased due to the lack of a battery.  Of note, this is quite an OLD computer, you'll be embarking on a low probability effort.  Why not just get a new computer and be done with it?

Comment: Some motherboards have an emergency mode where you can adjust a jumper or hold down some key combo while starting and it'll read the bios off a USB key. But your mobo is 14 years old... Still, worth searching for something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's repair your PC by replacing the corrupt chip with a working one or by getting your BIOS reflashed. If nothing helps, you'll need to buy a new motherboard.

Comment: duDE - The question is about how to reflash the BIOS.  Your answer is replace a chip, reflash the BIOS, or buy a new motherboard?  This isn't worthy of someone with your rep.

Comment: @fixer1234 What else is he supposed to do? I doubt the OP has the equipment to program BIOS chips.

Comment: Although I would like to see the format of the answer match the format of an actual answer this is valid advice.

Comment: Technically, the question was, "Is there any way to repair the problem?", so duDE's answer was a literal response and valid in that sense.  However, the OP was not simply taking a poll about whether methods exist, he was looking for a solution.  This answer was not actionable information, and did nothing to solve the problem.  It was a suggested search direction, which would have been appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There was a trick for fixing this type of problem in old motherboards, but it involved borrowing a BIOS chip from a working motherboard and hotswapping these chips (they were big socketed DIPs back in the old days). The procedure was as follows:

1. Prepare the BIOS update floppy
2. Put a working (not erased) BIOS chip in your motherboard
3. Boot the PC from the floppy (DO NOT start the tool yet)
4. Put the erased chip in
5. Run the tool and install the BIOS

By far not the most professional method, but it worked. A bit risky due to tampering with a powered-on machine.

Alternatively, just use an EEPROM programmer and program the BIOS chip with the .bin file containing the BIOS. This is the most professional method and is recommended, because nowadays it's easier to get hold of an EEPROM programmer than a working motherboard of the same model.